# Add custom button below wishlist button in PDP

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa, venia, react, react-js

We are using PWA venia theme 2.4.5. We are trying to add a button below ADD TO WISHLIST in PDP Page

We tried the below code . but we are not seeing any button.

```
{
  isMobile && (
    <div className={classes.cartActionButton}>
      <div className="px-3 h-[46px] m-auto w-full">
        {cartActionContent}
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} style={{ color: "red" }} />
        </Suspense>
        <button type="button">Custom button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is ProductFullDetail.js : https://pastebin.com/YBD5f5bG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have added a button code placed after WishlistButton button code line no. 984 into your file

```
<button
    className="custom-button"
    style={{
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(199, 164, 111) 0%, rgb(136, 108, 68) 100%);
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        justify-content: center;
    }}
>
    Custom Button
</button>
```

and remove this button code from line no. 1032

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

please add this code and try to add code.

Comment: thankyou, i will check it

Comment: please remove the style tag and after check

Comment: [link](https://frontend1.staging.glowjewels.com/dreamy-wonder-diamond-necklace) please check

Comment: apply the same code to the 1034 line where you can remove the first code so this is working on mobile also

Comment: added the code. it's visible initially and disappearing after the page load completely. is that the css issue ?

Comment: please add the different class into the button in mobile like a custom-button-mobile then I will try to apply CSS for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151041/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-rohit-gohel).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **{cartActionContent}** code in your **ProductfullDetail.js**

and then add the code below like :

```
{cartActionContent}
<Suspense fallback={null}>
   <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
</Suspense>
```

[image]

Comment: i am already using the same code [wishlist button is already there ] , can you please tell what new code i need to add for new button ?  I want the custom button below the wishlist button.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

```
<button type="button">Custom button</button>
```

to

```
<LinkButton
    className={
        ' max-h-[35px] py-2 focus:outline-none'
    }
    onClick={() =>
        alert('test');
    }
>
    <ChevronRight
        size={20}
        className="rounded-full border border-[#C77F44] text-[#C77F44]"
    />
</LinkButton>
```